# Incorrect sql request on count method with Play/Sybase/Hibernate when multiple PK

Tags: sql, hibernate, playframework, sap-ase

My model has multiple PK (3), I'm using the Play Framework with Hibernate, and the table mapped by my Model is stored in a Sybase db.

I made a Junit where the save()/find()/delete() works very well. But the count() method don't, it throws a SqlGrammarException. By setting `jpa.debugSQL=true` I trapped the sql request generated by Hibernate and it's  incorrect :

```
select count((systempara0_.interface, systempara0_.name, systempara0_.origine)) as col_0_0_ from system_parameters systempara0_
```

**Sybase doesn't allow commas in the count statement**, if I drop them and set only one column in the statement, the request runs well.

Am I wrong somewhere ?
Is there a bug in Hibernate ?
Is there a workaround ?

Thanks in advance

```
Sybase Version : Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.0.3
Play Framework 1.1.1
```

---

**Update :**
From the hibernate Javadoc, I noticed a method called `supportsTupleCounts()` in the `SybaseASE15Dialect` class, which returns false. 
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/Dialect.html#supportsTupleCounts()

BUT the Play framework 1.1.1 embeds Hibernate 3.5.6 where this method does not exists... That's the reason!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can downgrade the dialect-files. You can't change the hibernate version in play, because they made some patches.

Comment: Thanks I specified a custom Dialect which extends SybaseASE15Dialect , then override supportsTuppleCount to force return false and other tricks, but I didn't manage to fix this error.

Comment: Hmm I'm unfortunately not an expert in hibernate. Has you checked play 1.2? It contains Hibernate 3.6.0. Not perfect to run a alpha version, but it should become final this summer and I don't see any problems with 1.2. At least you can check if 3.6 solve your problem.

Comment: same issue in play 1.2 (master-705a72f)

Comment: Ok than Hibernate don't solve your problem :-(. You can try to analyze the play code and patch it. It's not difficult. Not my preferred advice, but at least a solution.

Comment: I don't think that patching play will fix my problem, because the issue is the sql generated by hibernate, just before sending this sql to the db. Thanks btw

Comment: If you use MyModel.count() you can change the class JPQL. There is the count-command declared. If you change the JQL-Befehl or use a primitive this should work. Another approach is to write your own JPAEnhancer which delegates to another Method, other the JPQL.count().

Comment: I've changed the JPQL class and my Model.count() work ! But in the CRUD module of play!, JPQL.instance isn't used so the count query failed again !